# Generate a weekly date on every year

Tags: php, arrays, date

Basically what I wanted is something like this, an array like

```
Array
(
    [20131020] => October 20 2013
    [20131027] => October 27 2013
    [20131103] => November 3 2013
    [20131110] => November 10 2013
)
```

where the indexes are the dates `yyyy-mm-dd` format and the corresponding value of each index is the equivalent `m-dd-yyyy` which is shown above. Can it be generated in `PHP` such that I can generate weekly dates of every year and on the coming years? Also another array which will look like this,

```
Array
(
    [20131020] => October 20 2013
        array(
            [20131020] = October 20 2013,
        [20131021] = October 21 2013,
        [20131022] = October 22 2013,
        [20131023] = October 23 2013,
        [20131024] = October 24 2013,
        [20131025] = October 25 2013,
        [20131026] = October 26 2013,
    )
    [20131027] => October 27 2013
        array(
        [20131020] = October 27 2013,
        [20131021] = October 28 2013,
        [20131022] = October 29 2013,
        [20131023] = October 30 2013,
        [20131024] = October 31 2013,
        [20131101] = November 01 2013,
        [20131102] = November 02 2013,
    )
)
```

I can't find any similar query with this so I made one instead. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: PHP can do a whole lot of stuff with dates. Look into [`DateTime()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) to get started.

Comment: But what's this gotta do with sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
$date     = new DateTime('2013-10-20');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1W');
$end      = new DateTime('2015-10-30');
$array    = array();

while($date < $end){
    $array[$date->format('Ymd')] = $date->format('F j, Y');
    $date->add($interval);
}

print_r($array);
```

Comment: How will I make the value of `$date` be the date this week? I tried using the date today but it yields incorrect results. Can the value of `$date` be dynamic such that it will be the date this week, for instance it will be `2013-13-20` this week and will then change to `2013-10-20` next week?

Comment: You can do: `$date = new DateTime('last sunday');` or `$date = new DateTime('next sunday');` to set the starting date to either the previous or next Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

Just start with a date and add 7 days until you want to stop.

For example (`$dates` will include all weeks after today for the rest of the year):

```
$theDate = time();
$dates = array();

while (date('Y', $theDate) == '2013') {
    $dates[] = $theDate;
    $theDate = strtotime('+7 days', $theDate);
}
```